# Is there a way to uninstall a program for a specific user (profile)?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I'm looking to separate out my development environment from my gaming and other misc items.  Is there a way to tell my system to uninstall the application(s) for only one user (profile) i.e.  Dev and Gaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible for the reason that an application is installed for everybody.

In some cases, an application is only installed for a single user, but then only that user has access to it in the first place.

That being said, you can disable access and prevent a certain user from using a program. You can do that through Group Policy, setting folder permissions, and a couple of other methods work.