# How can I delete mspaint from our work computers

Tags: windows-10

We need to prevent students using ms Paint on our work computers but it seems to be part of windows. How can I delete it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to uninstall a program for a specific user (profile)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1282148/is-there-a-way-to-uninstall-a-program-for-a-specific-user-profile)

Answer (score 1):

For getting rid of Paint 3D:

Open an elevated PowerShell and type the following command:

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.MSPaint | Remove-AppxPackage
```

To get rid of the "Edit with Paint 3D" option in the right-click context menu
for `.jpeg` files, use `regedit` to browse to :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.jpeg\Shell
```

Right-click the *3D Edit* key and click Delete.
Export first the key, just in case.

You could also use the following `.reg` file to delete the key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.jpeg\Shell\3D Edit]
```

For the old MSPaint, you will need to take ownership of the file
`C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe` and rename it.